# Encoding issue with data.sql in Spring Boot with Maven

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, character-encoding

I'm trying to test a data access library which contains Spring Data JPA entites and repositories.

My SpringBootTests create a database and populates it automatically with schema-test.sql and data-test.sql

In my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=test
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

In my data-test.sql, I have some latin characters. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
(ID, NAME)
VALUES
(1, 'Donnée');
```

My data-test.sql file is UTF-8 encoded. I doubled checked with Vim `:se fenc` and in Eclipse:
[image: File properties in Eclipse]

When I launch my JUnit test from Eclipse, everything works, my tests pass. But when I launch a maven package goal from Eclipse, my tests fail with something like:

```
Expecting:
  <Optional[TableEntity [id=1, name=DonnÃ©e]]>
to contain:
  <TableEntity [id=1, name=Donnée]>
but did not.
```

It seems that maven does not interpret my data-test.sql file as an UTF-8 encoded file, but as a CP-1252 encoded file.

I added the following in my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

and also:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <!-- Latin1 is still the default for .properties files -->
        <propertiesEncoding>ISO-8859-1</propertiesEncoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In the Eclipse "Run configuration", I added the following VM arguments :

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

and I also force the encoding in the "Common" tab:
[image: encoding on common tab]

In the console, I find:

```
[DEBUG] Copying file application.properties
[DEBUG] file application.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] Using 'ISO-8859-1' encoding to copy filtered resource 'application.properties'.
[DEBUG] copy (...)\src\test\resources\application.properties to (...)\target\test-classes\application.properties
[DEBUG] Copying file data-test.sql
[DEBUG] file data-test.sql has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resource 'data-test.sql'.
[DEBUG] copy (...)\src\test\resources\data-test.sql to (...)\target\test-classes\data-test.sql
[DEBUG] Copying file schema-test.sql
[DEBUG] file schema-test.sql has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resource 'schema-test.sql'.
[DEBUG] copy (...)\src\test\resources\schema-test.sql to (...)\target\test-classes\schema-test.sql
```

Is there a hidden option somewhere forcing Maven, or my SpringBootTest class to interpret the SQL file as an old CP-1252 or ISO-8859-1 encoding?

A full example is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/EricC-59/sql-encoding-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding problem seems to come from the surefire plugin. I added the following lines in the `<plugins/>` of my pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Problem solved: It seems that surefire launched the tests in its own JVM, with a ISO-8859-1 encoding.

The fixed project is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/EricC-59/sql-encoding-problem/tree/Problem-solved)

Answer (score 0):

Show your eclipse properties.
Should be "UTF-8" as well.

[image]

**Encoding in DB**

Check the encoding for the H2 database.
So set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.charset_name = "UTF-8"`
As you use spring boot you could also set as follow:

```
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
```

Comment: Yes, my data.sql shows as UTF-8 in Eclipse (I added a screenshot). Reminder: everything works fine from within Eclipse when I launch the tests (Run as JUnit Test). The problem only appears when I try to launch a maven "package".

Comment: I updated my response. Can you check the encoding of the H2 database? You could add the property I named or just make a break point and watch yourself in the H2 database before you read the value via your test code.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did it correctly: I added `spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;` in my application.properties. Eclipse doesn't recognize the "connectionProperties" part. I also tried to add `hibernate.hbm2ddl.charset_name=UTF-8` and `spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.charset_name=UTF-8`, and in both cases, Eclipse doesn't recognize the "hbm2ddl" part.
The result is the same. My encoding problem is still there when using the "maven path".

Comment: I updated the post with a link to the example project reproducing the issue on GitHub.